# updatepanel not working

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, list-view, updatepanel, chrome, firefox

I had made a list view in sharepoint 2010 which takes first name and last name as input fields. We can add multiple names. For that I have created an update panel to asynchronously add names at front end and after all names added user can submit it. It is working fine in SP2010 but when migrated to SP 2013 it is giving issues.When I hit "Add another Name" then in Chrome and Mozilla the whole page goes for a load(a blank page appears on same window where Add another name was hit) and that loading never ends. 
Can Anyone help with this update panel.

Comment: Were you ever able to find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used java script code for that or you are doing it by code behind?

As Update panel is not supported in Office 365 environment. It is working on SP2013 on premises environment. if you had handled that using Update Panel trigger than it is going to be refresh.

you can use java script code to Add/Remove multiple dynamic controls.

[Create dynamic TextBox using JavaScript in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-dynamic-textbox-using-JavaScript-in-ASP.Net.aspx)

Comment: hi Hardik.. I am using on button click code behind to add dynamic content... It is only working fine in IE...

Comment: have you used your code within if(!Page.isPostback)..

Comment: no.. I have simply wrote the code in button clicked event

Comment: is your control outside the update panel? as you have mentioned that you have used asynchronous method for update panel. There is some difference between asynchronouspostbak & postbak triggers.

Comment: no.. my whole code is inside the update panel... it is a migrated code..